# How to write this VALUES query in asyncpg?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, python-asyncio, asyncpg

I have a plain SQL query that looks like this

```
SELECT 
  v.* 
FROM 
  (
    VALUES 
      (
        'b72c2bdcf32127a022b82c21064ad802'
      ), 
      (
        'db21d20c5ea6ba9b736b44016b4b4320'
      ), 
      (
        '775ebc584ce94112830adbe877a454c2'
      ), 
      (
        '40fe0182c4a226445bad99c45bed034c'
      ), 
      (
        '3205fda395852b36d21963a42286bbb5'
      ), 
      (
        '194934b1ed78233736d09eca01634d4a'
      ), 
      (
        '1722d450a96b89db29a1c8d0b9da5d40'
      ), 
      (
        '44ff4d3a67e00e9ecb937815fa860ae5'
      ), 
      (
        'e99aaba0414dc176735c41b0e8394218'
      ), 
      (
        'a51da22ef7478d3bdb2946d95ca7a59b'
      ), 
      (
        '712266f536b1deb21d0acd3536d8a8ac'
      ), 
      (
        '4355d8b9a293ec70c08e82e2221244bd'
      ), 
      (
        '3b7936d98340e8677f300e1b9691a4df'
      ), 
      (
        '19124e54e6027445c65532a9f04da80a'
      ), 
      (
        'dc414c23c208d356956832d31bf78029'
      ), 
      (
        '591360c7829185ed6426cebcf8ef0973'
      ), 
      (
        '34d9b4732e03ac2f19700d41e91381e3'
      ), 
      (
        '11579cefc7633923990450004b44a51c'
      ), 
      (
        '7be08be35e70c4bb1f29723f1354ce0e'
      ), 
      (
        '172674d396371e6fc9818527564795ce'
      ), 
      (
        '04390dcbbe0299c17d64926e38fbfe20'
      ), 
      (
        '8749424a929ca2ed25bb92d6572958df'
      ), 
      (
        '5d18010f8da43b3d884f680f5f4faa12'
      ), 
      (
        'e97a9c67ae9161509e9927da1810585c'
      ), 
      (
        '7cbb79c8bb3139f4bf7345715c6aca7e'
      ), 
      (
        '97f30a0949a859eccc18a75d92063730'
      ), 
      (
        '6f67bd03a7a7b0b8c3a8ea932e0048a6'
      ), 
      (
        '6665b996b3709228ec9e2b39b127150f'
      ), 
      (
        '10671b983ca0a93c141bf19ca0ecd95e'
      ), 
      (
        '2761d64452b777c783f3a4afbd60c71e'
      )
  ) v(feed_item_id) 
where 
  not exists (
    select 
      1 
    from 
      feed_items ub 
    where 
      ub.feed_item_id = v.feed_item_id :: uuid
  );
```

If I wanted to build  this dynamically with a list, how do I write this query in asyncpg?

Answer (score 0):

Given a bunch of values like this

```
[{'feed_item_id': 'b72c2bdcf32127a022b82c21064ad802'}, {'feed_item_id': 'db21d20c5ea6ba9b736b44016b4b4320'}, {'feed_item_id': '775ebc584ce94112830adbe877a454c2'}, {'feed_item_id': '40fe0182c4a226445bad99c45bed034c'}, {'feed_item_id': '3205fda395852b36d21963a42286bbb5'}, {'feed_item_id': '194934b1ed78233736d09eca01634d4a'}, {'feed_item_id': '1722d450a96b89db29a1c8d0b9da5d40'}, {'feed_item_id': '44ff4d3a67e00e9ecb937815fa860ae5'}, {'feed_item_id': 'e99aaba0414dc176735c41b0e8394218'}, {'feed_item_id': 'a51da22ef7478d3bdb2946d95ca7a59b'}, {'feed_item_id': '712266f536b1deb21d0acd3536d8a8ac'}, {'feed_item_id': '4355d8b9a293ec70c08e82e2221244bd'}, {'feed_item_id': '3b7936d98340e8677f300e1b9691a4df'}, {'feed_item_id': '19124e54e6027445c65532a9f04da80a'}, {'feed_item_id': 'dc414c23c208d356956832d31bf78029'}, {'feed_item_id': '591360c7829185ed6426cebcf8ef0973'}, {'feed_item_id': '34d9b4732e03ac2f19700d41e91381e3'}, {'feed_item_id': '11579cefc7633923990450004b44a51c'}, {'feed_item_id': '7be08be35e70c4bb1f29723f1354ce0e'}, {'feed_item_id': '172674d396371e6fc9818527564795ce'}, {'feed_item_id': '04390dcbbe0299c17d64926e38fbfe20'}, {'feed_item_id': '8749424a929ca2ed25bb92d6572958df'}, {'feed_item_id': '5d18010f8da43b3d884f680f5f4faa12'}, {'feed_item_id': 'e97a9c67ae9161509e9927da1810585c'}, {'feed_item_id': '7cbb79c8bb3139f4bf7345715c6aca7e'}, {'feed_item_id': '97f30a0949a859eccc18a75d92063730'}, {'feed_item_id': '6f67bd03a7a7b0b8c3a8ea932e0048a6'}, {'feed_item_id': '6665b996b3709228ec9e2b39b127150f'}, {'feed_item_id': '10671b983ca0a93c141bf19ca0ecd95e'}, {'feed_item_id': '2761d64452b777c783f3a4afbd60c71e'}]
```

This is the best I could come up with

```
query = "SELECT v.* FROM (VALUES('" + "'),('".join(map(lambda z: z['feed_item_id'], values)) + "')) v(feed_item_id)  where not exists (select 1 from feed_items ub where ub.feed_item_id = v.feed_item_id::uuid);"
```